# Is there a way to center label in nested pie chart without using magic numbers as radius for Amchart v4?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

My problem: i would like to find an automatic way to center labels in donut chart cells. In my case each cells contains an array of complex objects, what i want is to show the number of those objects.

See:
[image]

Playing with radius, allowed me to find those values:

- First layer: -28
- Second layer: -20
- Third layer: -10
- Fourth layer: -8

I applied it as a quick fix but i don't like this solution, as it's fixed for 4 layers (what if I need to add an other layer ? etc....) and using "magic numbers" is unmaintenable...

Do you have a better solution ?

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/aliz/gwz7om9e/

Line 40:

```
 pieSeries.labels.template.radius = am4core.percent(positionRadiusInPie);
```

Note:
Using those attributes didn't work: "horizontalCenter", "VerticalCenter", "textAlign", "align".

EDIT: response to Bhavik Kalariya

This is what I get if I force one radius for all layers.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can at least get it down to just using one base constant of your choosing by using [an adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) approach on the label's `radius` to calculate the value you want for each series that is added to the chart using whatever formula you choose. Here's a basic formula that gave good results for me with your setup, where `BASE_INNER_LABEL_RADIUS` is set to -45.

```
    pieSeries.labels.template.adapter.add('radius', function(radius, target) {
      var chart = target.baseSprite; //chart stored in baseSprite of the AxisCircularLabel
      var index = chart.series.indexOf(target.dataItem.component); //corresponding series stored in the dataItem's component

      return am4core.percent(BASE_INNER_LABEL_RADIUS / (index + 2)); //Uses singular constant defined elsewhere, which is used in all series
    });
```

This will adjust itself according to the number of series you add to the chart. You can make this as robust as you want by making further tweaks if you have fewer series and want to make the labels even more centered.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lmujdfn/)

**Edit**

If you want to be even more generic, you can get at the [slice sprite](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/slice/) directly through the `target.dataItem.sprites` array (typically the first element, though you can loop through and look for an object whose `className` is `"Slice"` if you want to be super safe about it) and calculate your desired radius value using any of the numeric properties it has, such as `innerRadius`.

```
    pieSeries.labels.template.adapter.add('radius', function(radius, target) {
      var chart = target.baseSprite; //chart stored in baseSprite of the AxisCircularLabel
      var index = chart.series.indexOf(target.dataItem.component); //corresponding series stored in the dataItem's component
      return -(target.dataItem.sprites[0].innerRadius) / (index + 3); 
    });
```

You'll want to adjust this accordingly, of course.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lmujdfn/1/)